# Firebase is getting laggy if react-native debugger is not open

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

I have a basic chat app which contains only conversations and messages. A user can send a message and other one receives it. It's working good on simulator but when I upload my app to my device (iPhone SE) it's getting laggy.

I've found something, if **remote debugger** is open app is working very smoothly, otherwise it's starting to work like [second video](https://streamable.com/3we4j).

How is that problem related to react-native remote debugger?

#### What I've done?

I tried to configure offline data and I managed to setup. But it didn't make any difference.

#### Videos

[My app on the simulator](https://streamable.com/tqq0g)
[My app on my device](https://streamable.com/3we4j)

#### Send message code

```
const msg = {
    name,
    text,
    createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    senderId,
    receiverId,
  };
  const conversationId = createOneToOneMessageId(senderId, receiverId);
  const rootRef = firebase.firestore();
  const batch = rootRef.batch();

  const newMessageRef = rootRef
    .collection('conversations')
    .doc(conversationId)
    .collection('messages')
    .doc();

  batch.set(newMessageRef, msg);

  const updateSenderConversationRef = rootRef
    .collection('user-conversations')
    .doc(senderId)
    .collection('conversations')
    .doc(conversationId);

  batch.update(updateSenderConversationRef, {
    lastMessage: msg.text,
    lastMessageDate: msg.createdAt,
  });

  const updateReceiverConversationRef = rootRef
    .collection('user-conversations')
    .doc(receiverId)
    .collection('conversations')
    .doc(conversationId);

  batch.update(updateReceiverConversationRef, {
    lastMessage: msg.text,
    lastMessageDate: msg.createdAt,
  });

  batch.commit();
```

#### Question

- Is that "latency" happens because of batch write operation?
- Is there a difference between my device and the simulator for cloud firestore?
- And obviously, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: you may want to check [your network request](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/blob/master/docs/network-inspect-of-chrome-devtools.md) and see which steps are causing this issue. Review your `websocket` and `server` log. You don't need to run the debugger to test your code. add a `console.warn` inside your `batch` statement, check your server and see if the request is generated in delay or if your server does not respond immediately.

Comment: For chat app, you will need to use [firebase realtime database][1]. Consider that when you work with debug console enabled, the communication speed is much better since java parser is in your pc, so 
the communication is by a better internet connection(possibly wired).

  [1]: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database

Comment: Did you try the release version of the app ? When the code is compiled, any lag should be removed.

Comment: @RocKhalil Yes, i’ve tried but still the result is same.

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio Firestore can work without network connection and if I use my phone in airplane mode, still it works laggy. So, I think it's not about network connection.

Comment: @ccoeder rather than wait for the message to propagate through firebase. Why don't you on send add it to the screen manually and then it will be overwritten when the firebase updates causing a re-render?